# How to use one coupan code for multiple prices discount?

Tags: discount, coupon, promotions

I am trying to set up a coupon which will give different discounts depending on how much is in the cart. 
So for example:

`Spend £20+ get 10% off
Spend £40+ get 20% off
Spend £60+ get 25% off`

I want to use only one coupon code. Can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Coupon` class in custom module and then comment below mention piece of code then it will save multiple coupan with same coupon code

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('salesrule/coupon', 'coupon_id');

    // Comment this code

    /*$this->addUniqueField(array(
        'field' => 'code',
        'title' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Coupon with the same code')
    )); */
}
```